# Podman rootful containers not getting exposed

Tags: networking, containers, podman

recently i installed ubuntu and podman on it.I want to run 3 websites, 1 db and 1 apache (as reverse proxy).I wanted to do it rootless, but i am having the problem because one of the websites has to be accessed only by some ips.In rootless networking after i create my network, its not reading clients real IP , but its allways giving them virtual(in podman network subnet) and that means that i cannot configure that only some ips have acces to one of websites , its or all or noone(Because i have to give acces to podman network subnet, so hat i can acces website at all).

I have tryed with --network slirp4netns:port_handler=slirp4netns, but then every container is in its own namespace and they cannot talk to each other. After that i wanted to try to run everything as root, to see if i can get it working, but the problem is that i can acces to websites only from that server, i cannot even acces websites from local network.(Firewall is not a problem, because i can acces websites when runing rootless). Am i doing something wrong, why are rootful containers not geting exposed ?